# Security token service and custom claims provider - strange error

Tags: linq, security-token-service, claim-provider

I have a custom claims provider, which uses some services from another assembly. This service assembly basically uses Linq-to-SQL context to read data from database which then custom claims provider uses to augment claims.

The problem is, that this mechanism works OK, and suddenly users can't log in, because SecurityTokenService fails to issue token, because there is an error in custom claims provider, which comes from service assembly. It fails randomly, and I assume problem is with linq data context (see stacktrace).

For now we fix this by restarting iis periodically, but we need to find out better solution.

Example stacktrace with error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
at Read_Szkola(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1.get_Entity()
at MiscServices.DAO.RocznikoKlasa.get_Szkola1()
at MiscServices.Model.ClassItem.CreateFromYearClassEntity(RocznikoKlasa klasa)
```

Strangest thing is that it all works and sudenly this invalid cast exception occurs. Any ideas what might be the cause and how I could solve this issue?

### Update

As requested, I paste below my model:

```
public class ClassItem
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SchoolItem School { get; set; }
        public int StartYear { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        public static ClassItem CreateFromYearClassEntity(RocznikoKlasa klasa)
        {
            if (klasa == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("klasa");
            return new ClassItem
            {
                ID = klasa.ID,
                Name = klasa.Nazwa,
                StartYear = klasa.RokRozpoczecia,
                Symbol = klasa.SymbolOddzialu,
                School = SchoolItem.CreateFromEntity(klasa.Szkola1)
            };
        }       

    }

public class ClassItem
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public SchoolItem School { get; set; }
        public int StartYear { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }

        public static ClassItem CreateFromYearClassEntity(RocznikoKlasa klasa)
        {
            if (klasa == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("klasa");
            return new ClassItem
            {
                ID = klasa.ID,
                Name = klasa.Nazwa,
                StartYear = klasa.RokRozpoczecia,
                Symbol = klasa.SymbolOddzialu,
                School = SchoolItem.CreateFromEntity(klasa.Szkola1)
            };
        }
    }

public class SchoolItem
    {
        public string Code;
        public JstItem JST;
        public string Name;
        public string City;
        public string PostCode;
        public string Street;
        public string Telephone;
        public string Fax;
        public string Email;

        public static SchoolItem CreateFromEntity(MiscServices.DAO.Szkola school)
        {
            if (school == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("school");
            return new SchoolItem {
                Code = school.Kod,
                Name = school.Nazwa,
                City = school.Miasto,
                Street = school.Ulica,
                PostCode = school.KodPocztowy,
                Telephone = school.Telefon,
                Fax = school.Fax,
                Email = school.Email,
                JST = JstItem.CreateFromEntity(school.JST1)
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the code inside CreateFromYearClassEntity(RocznikoKlasa klasa)? You might have a `nullable` property that is returning null or it has changed in the database and not updated in the mapping.

Comment: Looks like an datatype inference error. You may be able to get away with catching an int64 being returned and fliping it to a string before consuming it.

Comment: I provided implementation for my model.

Comment: i had similar issue where i had service which had code for error logging in c drive of server . While logging errors file opening and closing was not done properly . So the custom STS never issued a valid token . But when you reset , all the resources are released and it works .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the timeout is set correctly on the security token service. This can be set in powershell as follows.

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.FormsTokenLifeTime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 30)
$sts.Update()
Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
```

Some further examples can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147183(v=office.14).aspx
http://aleksaron.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/set-token-lifetime-that-comes-from-sts/

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try... make sure you are disposing the `DataContext` objects correctly. Even though the LinQ documentation will say that this is not required,  you should definitely dispose those objects.

The reason why your application works "for a while" is that you are leaking SQL connections. When the process runs out of connections it will start throwing extrange exceptions like the one you are seeing.

**EDIT**

Just found another post with the exact same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318716/asp-net-mvc-iis6-error-on-high-traffic-specified-cast-is-not-valid).